# Copy folders between sites with PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, pnp-powershell

We are trying to copy folders between sites. It works with files. We get following error:

Copy-PnPFile : The directory is not a subdirectory of the root directory.

```
$Site = 'illemann-05-testsite' 
$TSite = 'illemann-04-testsite'

$SiteUrl  = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/"+$site
$TSiteUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/"+$Tsite

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Siteurl  -AppId $config.AppId -AppSecret $config.appsecret #-RequestTimeOut $infinite
#Connect-PnPOnline -Url $TSiteurl -AppId $config.AppId -AppSecret $config.appsecret #-RequestTimeOut $infinite

# this works:
$SourceFolderURL = "testdoc/test.docx"
$TargetFolderURL = "/Sites/illemann-04-testsite/testdoc/test2.docx"

$SourceFolderURL = "testdoc/MyDocs"
$TargetFolderURL = "/Sites/illemann-04-testsite/testdoc"

Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl $SourceFolderURL -TargetUrl $TargetFolderURL -Force -SkipSourceFolderName

write-host "Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl " $SourceFolderURL  "-TargetUrl " $TargetFolderURL "-Force -SkipSourceFolderName"
```

The directories exists and we have recreated the sample in the Microsoft documentation. Any pointers?

Comment: Could be related to this bug maybe: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/2195 ?

Comment: Hi Anders Aune. Thanks for your answer. The folders we are trying to copy are not empty, and the documents are not empty.